# Why is datetime handled differently between Delphi XE7 64 bit and 32 bit?

Tags: sql, delphi, datetime, 32bit-64bit

I use a SQL statement:

```
select * from manifests where mftDate between :startdate and :enddate
```

This is using ADOQuery, xe7, Windows 7 64 bit.  The values are selected from datetime pickers

```
mftQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('startdate').value := startdatePicker.datetime;
mftQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('enddate').value := enddatePicker.datetime;
```

When I execute this from the 64 bit compile, everything works.

When I recompile as 32 bit, it compiles.  When I execute, though, it throws an error that the *parameter is of the wrong type*.

How should a date be coded to function under both 32 bit and 64 bit versions?

mftDate is defined in MS SQL 2008 as date, nulls allowed.

I tried using DateToStr() function on the datetime values.  Did not work.  However, I coded in a routine that seems to work now:

```
function TForm1.fixDate(myDate : TDateTime) : string;
var myYear, myMonth, myDay : word;
begin
  DecodeDate(myDate, myYear, myMonth, myDay);
  result := IntToStr(myYear) + '-' + IntToStr(myMonth) + '-' + IntToStr(myDay);
end;
```

For the life of me, I have NO clue why this works!

Comment: What type is mftDate?

Comment: There are not the answer but some suggestions to workaround: 1) Use `.AsDateTime` instead of `.Value` 2) Call `Parameters.Refresh` and then `Parameters.ParamByName('foo').DataType := ftDateTime;` 3) If you working with MS SQL (aka SQL server) try to declare variable in the query like `declare @startdate date = :p_startdate;` (may be inaccurate, not using MS SQL for a some time) and then something like `select * from ttt where ddd = @startdate`

Comment: That's a terrible solution to your problem. Are you happy with it, or would you like to do it properly?

Comment: @David I'm guessing that seeing that it's a question here and he's not closed it he wants to do it properly. I'd suggest a reason that DateToStr may fail is if it's string date format didn't match the DB's. Not sure why the param setting isn't working, though. I assume XXXDatePicker.datetime IS a TDateTime?

Comment: @Matt No need to assume: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.DateTime

Comment: Ah, didn't recognise the base component as I've not used base VCL components in ages. Suggest going into debug DCU for the .Value setter and finding out what TParam.SetAsVariant thinks the VarType of the value is. Another unrelated thing to be aware of is dangers of running Between queries with dates - the time component can confuse things

Comment: @Abelisto I tried your suggestions, and there is some progress, but not a working solution yet.  On 1) .AsDateTime is not allowed.  2) removed the parameter entirely after the refresh, so the DataType assignment failed because it could not find it by name.  This did alert me to check the design side, and I changed the definition from widestring to datetime.  That compiled clean, but when I run it now, it reports an "unknown  error".  At least there is something progressing.  I will continue to play with this.  I did not try using a stored procedure.

Comment: @Abelisto - Thanks for your input.  Changing the parameter type to ftDateTime was the solution.  The "unknown error" I got while testing was because the data I selected returned empty, and the IDE was throwing the error at me.  Running outside of the IDE, the program worked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of allowing the Delphi IDE to assign a default type of widestring to the SQL parameter, I changed the type to ftDateTime.  The code line then became:

```
mftQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('startdate').value := DateToStr(startdatePicker.datetime);
mftQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('enddate').value := DateToStr(enddatePicker.datetime);
```

Thanks to Abelisto for pointing me into a new direction!  I had not thought to check out the type of the parameter.

Comment: Nice to see that you have solved your problem. Good luck :)